# How to add a command to the context menu of ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ado.net-entity-data-model, vspackage, visual-studio-extensions

Basically, I need the correct values for `guid` and `id` attributes in the `.vsct` file of my Visual Studio package project, as in:

```
<Group guid="guidVSPackage1CmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
  <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
</Group>
```

The above comes straight from the default project template, and adds a command to the Tools main menu. Where can I find (or how do I sniff) the guid:id values for ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer context menu, the one with "Update Model from Database..." and so on?

Before you ask: the MEF extensibility options in VS 2010 Entity Designer do not cover my scenario - I need to implement a command to convert between independent and FK-mapped associations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. You need to decompile the compiled command table in Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Package.dll with vsct.exe from VS2010 SDK directory (just extract the EntityDesigner.ctmenu with Reflector, rename it to EntityDesigner.cto then run vsct.exe passing the path to EntityDesigner.cto as the only parameter). For another VSPackage to load when the context menu is opened, you need to at least declare them with `DynamicVisibility` flag, as such:

```
<Button guid="guidVSPackage1CmdSet" id="cmdidMyCommand"
        priority="0x0100" type="Button">
  <Parent guid="guidVSPackage1CmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" />
  <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
  <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
  <Strings>
    <CommandName>cmdidMyCommand</CommandName>
    <ButtonText>My Command name</ButtonText>
  </Strings>
</Button>
```

The actual IDs are:

```
<GuidSymbol name="guidCmdSetEntityDesigner"
       value="{11ac0a76-365e-490d-abad-e44e52897c7d}">
  <IDSymbol name="menuidContext" value="0x00010000" />
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. Yes, working for me now in VS2012.
I see you found the answer to your own question in 3 hours (!) which beats me and hence my search here.
Thanks